# How to play Web Audio in earpiece

Tags: web, webrtc, html5-audio, apprtcdemo, openwebrtc

I am implementing a WebRTC project for mobile devices using Cordova, in that I want the play the audio in earpiece of mobile device instead of speaker.

Is there any API/ way to play audio in earpiece,

I'm using cordova-plugin-iosrtc for iOS app and cross-walk for android.

Thanks,
Shinto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
cordova.plugins.iosrtc.selectAudioOutput('earpiece');
```

Here you can find [iosrtc documentation](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/iosrtc.md#iosrtcselectaudiooutputoutput)

Comment: Thank you nsanchez

Comment: this function has been removed.: https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/commit/6480fcad91604eddfb045e93343b55ee5773caf2
It suggested to use this instead: https://github.com/saghul/cordova-plugin-audioroute